# Recreate same private key from same passphrase in Nodejs' crypto

Tags: node.js, public-key-encryption, private-key, cryptojs, key-pair

Long story short, I want to have the ability of the private key to be generated "on the fly" by the user/client, while the files on the server use the public key to get encrypted upon creation.

I practically need help with figuring out under which protocol that is possible and what parameters I should pass statically into it, to eliminate the randomness of the creation process.

Although I will be using Node's `crypto.generateKeyPair`, I think this may be useful to have around as a general question, since most key-generating algorithms tend to work similarly...

Comment: You are asking about 'deterministic' key generation. I would use an Elliptic KeyPair as basis, generate it with a 'fixedSecureRandom' [instead of the 'real' SecureRandom] that is seeded with a key generated by a key dervation method like PBKDF2. As PBKDF2 needs a random salt this should be generated and stored on clients device. As I'm working mostly on Java I cannot help you in any libraries or codes for doing this workflow using node.js, sorry.

Comment: It's ok, you've given me an answer at the form of key I should look into, which is probably the most important and juicy part of the question! Thanks a lot!